# Reading the value of a Math.random generated button label

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on an exercise that is asking me to do the following;

1. Create a GridPane
2. Set the pane’s horizontal and vertical gap to zero
3. Set the pane’s grid line visibility to true
4. Use nested FOR loops to create and add buttons to the pane (loops 
       starts from 0 to 10)
5. Each button must be labeled with any number between 0 to 99
6. Color the buttons based on the following rules:
   a.  If the color’s label is divisible by 2, then change the color to Blue
   b.  If the color’s label is divisible by 3, then change the color to 
       Yellow
   c.  If the color’s label is divisible by 6, then change the color to Green
7. Add the pane to a scene
8. Add the scene to a stage, then display the Stage

I have everything set up, just not sure how to read the value generated by Math.random and do assign a specific color to that button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;



public class Exercise8GridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) {
        primary.setTitle("Exercise 8");
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setHgap(0);
        gp.setVgap(0);
        gp.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {                
                Button btn = new Button(String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 100)));
                // if / 3 == 0){
                btn.setStyle("-fx-base:red;-fx-text-fill:yellow"); 

                  gp.add(btn, l, k);  
            }

        }
        Scene s = new Scene(gp);
        primary.setScene(s);
        primary.show();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  What is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: It sounds like you are actually asking how to implement step 6.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am stuck trying to implement step 6.

Comment: Note that for generating `int`s creating an instance of `Random` and using its `nextInt` method is more convenient. As for the question: Not sure what exactly the problem here is: Determining, if an `int` is divisible by a certain number? Setting the color given the color name? ...?

Comment: Start by placing the random value into a variable:  `int value = (int)(Math.random() * 100); Button btn = new Button(String.valueOf(value));`  The tests described in step 6 can be accomplished with the modulo operator (`%`).

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.Math.random() returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.

There are countless ways to read it.

I would recommend doing something like

```
int RED = (int) (Math.random() * 256); 
// Note that Math.random() returns a value less than 1.0 
int BLUE = ...
```

It's difficult to get three values from one number, so I think this will work well.

Comment: It appears the question was about interpreting the random value, not just reading it.  The title is misleading.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I've edited my question to include a way.